# React App to fetch json data getting an error?

Tags: json, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a Home.js and included inside App.js of my react app.I want to fetch json data but I am getting the following error-
[image]

My Code- https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kwaooy?file=src/App.js

Comment: You example link only shows a react hooks error.

Comment: Please post the json you receive so that we could see if it's actually an array :)

Comment: @DeanJames I know but I was getting the above given error on the localhost.Can you please tel me what the hell is wrong with my code?

Comment: @k-wasilewski The link of json data is already given in the code.By the way, here is the link- https://api.apify.com/v2/key-value-stores/toDWvRj1JpTXiM8FF/records/LATEST?disableRedirect=true

Comment: What is the structure you expect for `this.state.lists`? You initialise it as an empty array `[]`, but then in your render you're looking for named properties, implying it's an object. I'm also confused about your API call, where you name your data `list` 
(singular) but then assign that to `lists` (plural)

Comment: @DeanJames I have created lists(plural) inside state as an empty array.Then,with the help of axios i have assign list(singular) which contains json data inside lists(plural).How to access the json data thats all i want to know.

Answer (score 2):

For initial load your `this.state.lists.regionData` will be undefined and you are accessing the undefined value that might be the issue for crashing the application.

Change your state value like below,

```
 this.state = {
      lists: {
          regionData: [],
          activeCases: '',
          activeCasesNew: '',
          deaths: ''
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what you are actually storing in the list state from the response. What I see is that you are storing response.data but you might actually want to store regionData from the response. This will allow map to iterate over the regionData values and not show this error.

Comment: Yes, I want to access regionData but I also want to access other data outside of regionData.It is so frustating to work for hours to solve these small things.By the way here is the link of json data- https://api.apify.com/v2/key-value-stores/toDWvRj1JpTXiM8FF/records/LATEST?disableRedirect=true

Comment: I understand that, but that isn't how map works. The data outside the regionData object is preventing map from working correctly. I suggest you split the response up into two parts and store them individually in your states

Comment: No worry,I got the solution on my own thanks for your help.